# Synchronize project members in phabricator using REST

Tags: rest, phabricator

Is there a way to synchronize project members in phabricator automatically for example using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. Feel free to file a request here describing your use case:

https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/task/create/

See also:

https://secure.phabricator.com/T3980 (Support "LDAP group" in policy infrastructure)

Comment: Is now any way to manage projects/users? Or everything must be done from WWW?